# Why classify all singularities? Application of classification

Tags: algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables, singularity-theory

I was given a book about classifying all singularities of a complex hypersurface.

What is the importance of classifying all singularities?

In which areas do singularities pop up and how does understanding them help?

Comment: classification always is important in any math component.

Comment: @m-agag2016 that's true, but I can convince you classifying finitely generated abelian groups is more important than classifying number whose decimal expansion contains pi. There is much value in connection to other fields

Comment: Will you accept that classifying varieties is important? Dealing with singularities is critical even in classifying smooth varieties.

Comment: @TabesBridges Sure I will. But I'd be happy to hear connections to more fields.

Comment: If you have a potentially nonlinear equation in several variables and are looking for solutions (something that seems to happen in essentially any field, pure or applied, math, physics, engineering,...), then you are looking at a complex hypersurface.  Knowing what a singularity looks like makes it possible to describe the set of solutions.  In fact, I am having a hard time thinking of fields where such equations NEVER come up and where understanding the set of solutions would NEVER be helpful.